# Is -i negative?

Tags: complex-numbers

It's pronounced "negative i," yet I'm told complex numbers aren't negative or positive. Is the `-` just arbitrary and unreflective of -i's sign?

Comment: I pronounce it "minus $i$". Of course if $x$ is a negative number, say $x=-4$, then $-x$ (pronounced "minus $x$") is a positive number.

Comment: $i$ doesn't have a "sign", neither does $-i$. But there are two complex numbers that square to minus one, and they are additive inverses, so if we call one of them $i$, we have little choice but to call the other one $-i$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown but i is a constant, so negative i implies that one version of i is positive and the other negative (even if i is the negative one)

Comment: @alec935 Is it your insistence on pronouncing $-$ as "negative" the source of your problem? The unary minus sign maps an object to its additive inverse. If you had a vector $v$ in three-dimensional space, would you insist one of $v$ and $-v$ was positive, and one negative? All this notation means is that they have the same length and point in opposite directions.

Comment: @alec935 It implies nothing of the sort.  The complex numbers do not come with an order relation.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I quite like that answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To paraphrase what has transpired in the comments, and bring some closure to the question: it looks like an ambiguity of understanding of "-/minus/negative."

### Minus

Foremostly, $-$ is used as a binary operation: $a-b$, which one could comfortably call "minus." Since your question only involves the unary use of $-$, we'll skip this case in favor of the other two.

### Negative

On one hand, we have *concrete representation of real numbers* and *their notion of order* which we have traditionally affixed the "-" prefix to the ones less than zero and called them *negative numbers*. In this case we talk about $-2$ and $3$ in $\mathbb R$ and there isn't any ambiguity about where they lie, because we follow the convention that the negative numbers are the ones below $0$.

This is wholly due to the total order on $\mathbb R$, which of course not all rings have.  Rings that can't be totally ordered include things like $\mathbb C$ and finite rings.

### Additive inverse

On the other hand, "-" the notational prefix for "additive inverse," connects pairs of elements (not necessarily distinct elements) by the relationship that the two elements add up to $0$.  So, we can talk about $x\in\mathbb R$ and $-x\in \mathbb R$ without ever deciding if $x$ lies above $0$, below zero, or exactly at zero.  The symbol in front doesn't presuppose anything about the ordering of $\mathbb R$, just its addition operation.

The problem here, perhaps, is that we don't have a snappy name we use consistently that connotes this usage. People say "minus x" and "negative x" interchangeably, without considering that the first suggests a binary operation and the second suggests an ordering.

A more accurate name for $-x$ would be "(additive) inverse of x," but it's a bit of a mouthful when reading expressions for a basic algebra class.

### Thought experiment

Let's pretend we're in a universe where take the whole situation and transfer it over to multiplication in $\mathbb R$. We have the notation $x^{-1}$ which we're going to confuse in the same way.

In an ordered ring (like $\mathbb R$) call an element $x$ "tiny" if $0<|x|<1$, and "magnitudinous" if $|x|>1$ ($1$ is neither small nor large, and $0$ is conspicuously missing, and we'll let it stay that way.) In our new system, we'll also never write a tiny positive number starting with "$0.$" or "$-0.$", our concrete representation of it will just be as an inverse of a magnitudinous number: e.g. there is no $0.5$, only $2^{-1}$. So, you can immediately and conveniently recognize "tiny" numbers as those with $-1$ floating up and to the right, and one might pronounce $2^{-1}$ as "tiny 2$."

The analogous situation in this thought experiment is that people refer to $x^{-1}$ ambiguously as "divided by $x$" and "tiny $x$," but they only call it "the multiplicative inverse of $x$" on formal occasions.

### Your question

> I'm told complex numbers aren't negative or positive. Is the - just arbitrary and unreflective of -i's sign?

The first statement is correct in general (although one might still call the positive real numbers inside $\mathbb C$ positive.)

It is arbitrary in the sense that it is a notational choice. For example if you have any complex number $\alpha$, you could locate its additive inverse $\beta$ and write $\alpha=-\beta$ and it doesn't change anything about $\alpha$ besides the way it looks on paper.

Finally $i$ *doesn't have a "sign"* in the sense that real numbers "have a sign," because $\mathbb C$ can't be split up into a positive and a negative piece like the real numbers can, for the reasons mentioned before.

Answer (score 4):

To extend the real numbers so that the equation $x^2=-1$ has a root is the same as requiring that $x^2+1$ factorizes—say as $(x-a)(x-b)$. It is easy to see that $a$ and $b$ cannot be the same: they are two things. However, they are related: they must satisfy $a+b=0$. Another way of saying this is $a=-b$, or we could equally well say $b=-a$. Each is the negative of the other; but there is no way of deciding that one is primary and the other is derived from it—for example that $a$ is “positive” and $b$ is “negative”. These terms have no meaning off the real line. Rather than having to deal with two names (such as $a$ and $b$), along with the condition that each is the negative of the other, it is convenient just to arbitrarily appoint one to have a simple name, and attach a minus sign to it to denote the other: thus $\mathrm i$ and $-\mathrm i$.

While convenient, this choice of symbolism has the unfortunate effect of suggesting that $\mathrm i$ is in some sense the primary “square root of minus one” while $-\mathrm i$ is derived from it. But we can no more put them in order than we can put an order on Tweedledum and Tweedledee (or perhaps I should say Tweedledee and Tweedledum).